# Store JSON data in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016

I want to store JSON data in SQL SERVER 2014 table. Can anyone tell me how can I do so. Is this even possible in 2014 version ?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 does not support JSON, so you can use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` column to store JSON data. You will not be able to use any of the JSON T-SQL extensions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as SQL Server is concerned, up until 2016 version, JSON is just a string. You can store it using `nvarchar` with whatever size that fits (I would suggest avoiding `max` whenever possible).
I don't know about older versions, but in 2016 version, you can also store Json in an XML data type field, with one exception - if your Json contains the `&` char, you need to replace it with `&amp;` otherwise you will get an error.

Starting with 2016 version, you can also use the database new JSON features, namely [`ISJSON`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isjson-transact-sql), [`JSON_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql), [`JSON_QUERY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql) and [`JSON_MODIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-modify-transact-sql)